# How to share angular library without NPM

Tags: angular, angular-library

I'm developing a component library which I don't want to share in npmjs, is there any way to share my angular library with other angular projects with out sharing it with NPM.

Comment: @nrwl has a great architecture that can be used for a lot of things. Their architecture is based on local shared libraries. Visit their site (nrwl.io) There's a section containing training material (https://connect.nrwl.io/app/dashboard). After registering you have access to free ebooks. On of them is of special interest: Enterprise Angular Monorepo Patterns and it describes how to professionally do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes try **verdaccio** which stores ur packaged library in your local storage when u npm i **libraryname** first it searches for library in local storage and then searches for public npm
https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/installation

Answer (score 0):

The best way - to have your own npm registry and publish in it. It's often in medium or big companies.

Easier way - to publish your package library in git repository and add lobrary as package with git source. You can see how to do it in npm documentation. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies